# Searching for questions with a tag only gives bountied questions

Tags: bug, user-interface, search

Whan I search for a tag on the main site, the list produced seems to have the added proviso that there is a bounty attached to the post.

For example:
[image: search for a tag]

It works properly on math.meta, and also works on the few other StackExchange sites I have tried.

In case it's relevant, I'm using FireFox 77.0.1 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your selection, right to the "0 questions with bounties" is set to "Bountied". Change to "Active" or "Newest".

[image]

Comment: Argh!!! I don't use the search facility very often. At least it's as simple as it is embarrassing. Thanks very much.

Comment: Probably it is worth mentioning that those tabs are *sticky*. If you choose some of those options for one tag - let us say frequent - then you get to the frequent tab when you choose some other tag. (I.e., the software remembers your last choice.) So if you switch to *active* now, then when you look at another tag, you will still be in the active tab until you change it manually.

Comment: @Martin, so I have to perform one possibly irrelevant search to get to this page where I  can select the option I want?

Comment: @PeterPhipps: Searching *only* a single tag leads you to the tag's "main page". You can just click on a tag and you'll get the same result. E.g., [tag:axiom-of-choice].

Comment: @PeterPhipps Not really. Whenever you get to the search results, you can change the tab which you want. Similarly, if you're displaying the list of all questions, you can choose one of those tabs.